# Services binding to 127.0.0.2, not responding on 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, networking

I have an OpenVZ host and running several services on it (mongodb, bitcoind). I only intend to connect to them locally. They all seem to bind to 127.0.0.2 - the `venet` interface. When I try to access a service at 127.0.0.1 (the default for the clients), I get get no response. However connecting on 127.0.0.2 works fine. I didn't realize it was possible for there to be a difference between the two. What's happening here?

Here's an output of ifconfig:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:199957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:199957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:15822725 (15.8 MB)  TX bytes:15822725 (15.8 MB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1dc0:2003::adb9:ca98/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1dc0:2003::a59d:5802/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1dc0:2003::8d9f:638b/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1dc0:2003::8638:9f63/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1dc0:2003::daef:a10a/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1dc0:2003::92b9:5c2a/128 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:389890 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:341645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:367108643 (367.1 MB)  TX bytes:98312087 (98.3 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:178.17.169.91  P-t-P:178.17.169.91  Bcast:178.17.169.91  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Here's my /etc/hosts file:

```
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.2 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
178.17.169.91 btslots.com  btslots
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

I changed localhost to have it point to 127.0.0.2. I'm surprised that it's possible for two addresses that are in the 127.0.0.1/8 subnet to give different results. All addresses besides 127.0.0.1 act the same (and as expected).

Comment: You have OpenVZ. It does networking... strangely. For a variety of reasons, I don't recommend using OpenVZ.

Comment: Can you set the listen or local address in each of those applications specifically to 127.0.0.1? Also, can you include the ipv4 content of your `/etc/hosts` file? You may be able to convince it to use 127.0.0.1 by mucking about with the order of lines, names and addresses in there (or you might make a total mess of things, so make a copy first)

Comment: I did notice that OpenVZ does networking "strangely". It's what is supplied by my VPS provider so switching away from it involves paying more money. I want to understand what exactly it's actually doing - OpenVZ seems to be pretty common among VPS providers so I'm assuming plenty of people manage to make it work for them.

Comment: I can indeed switch the IP address used by the clients and am doing that currently. Though I would still like to understand what is happening.

Comment: OpenVZ is pretty common, but that doesn't make it good, or appropriate for a given purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple, different loopback devices under 127.0.0.0/8 subnet is not uncommon. For example, you can implement them in [FreeBSD jail](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/jails-ezjail.html) setups to isolate loopback traffic to the specific jails.

127.0.0.0/8 is a subnet like any other subnet (with the exception that traffic destined to it should ["loop"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) back inside the host), and 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 are distinct destinations when they are bound to two different interfaces.